# replace multiple strings in a file using ksh

Tags: filenames

I have a directory in which all the files are listed with `.ear`. I want to remove the `.ear` and keep only the file name. Is I possible?

When I try

```
cd /path/
ls >> file
```

then in the output file `file` the directory names that are stored contain all the files including `.ear` at the end. I want to remove the `.ear` and just keep the name of that file.

Comment: You talk about files in a directory with a certain `.ear` filename suffix, but then seem to want to modify an XML file? If you want to modify an attribute or value in an XML file, then you will have to show us the file (or a relevant portion of it) so that we can help you parse it properly, likely with an XML parser rather than with some line-oriented text editing tool. Also mention what Unix you are using. The specific shell you're using is less important.

Comment: wan to modify the list of strings(name of files with ear extension) that are present in a file

Comment: Ok, so show us the structure of that XML file. Without knowing what the data looks like, there is no way of suggesting a command that will work.

Comment: name of the file is file.   and in that file...the contents are gcvcvd.ear and then in next linegvgdhvj.ear and so on

Comment: It would help if you could [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/583499/edit) your question to include an excerpt from the XML file. You can anonymize sensitive information if needed, but otherwise it is almost impossible to help you find a solution to the issue.

Comment: @AdminBee i ahve edited the description part

Comment: Ok, that's clearer. Are there _only_ files ending in `.ear`, or possibly others, too? Are there sub-directories in the directory?

Comment: You removed the mentioning of the XML file altogether now, so I'm confused as to what you want to do.

Comment: @Kusalananda I think the task at hand is really just generating a file that contains a list of the directory content, where alle filenames have the `.ear` suffix stripped.

Comment: @AdminBee there are only ear files

Answer (score 3):

To create a list of names of files in the directory `/path` that have filenames ending with `.ear`, while removing that suffix:

```
for name in /path/*.ear; do
    basename "$name" .ear
done >list
```

The `basename` utility returns the filename portion of a pathname, and if a second argument is provided, that is taken as a string that should be stripped from the end of each name.

In the loop above, we iterate over only the files that match the pattern `/path/*.ear`, extract the filename without the `.ear` suffix, and write the list to a file called `list`.

This would also correctly handle filenames containing newlines, like the  filename

```
$'my.left.ear\ncollection 1.ear'
```

Answer (score 2):

You want:

```
ls *.ear | sed 's/\.ear$//' >list.txt
```

If you don't like using the output of `ls` you can also do:

```
printf "%s\n" *.ear | sed 's/\.ear$//' >list.txt
```

In shells where `printf` is not a built-in (or with the `ls` form above) you can theoretically hit a limit on the number of arguments, but if these EAR files are the ones I'm familiar with, you won't get thousands of them.